# segmentation fault using jest and discord.js

Tags: node.js, jestjs, discord.js, segmentation-fault, nestjs

I'm using jest nodejs (nestjs) and discord.js

during the development my code works, during jest tests I get this error

```
[1]    49780 segmentation fault  npm run test:e2e
```

Debugging, I notice that this call creates the problem

```
channel.send({ 'content': 'xxx', 'files':[file] } )
```

file is an AttachmentBuilder object like:

```
    AttachmentBuilder {
      attachment: <Buffer ff... 510935 more bytes>,
      name: undefined,
      description: undefined
   }
```

If I use

```
channel.send({ 'content': 'xxx' } )
```

my tests work.

My import is:

```
import { Client, Partials, Collection, GatewayIntentBits, TextChannel, AttachmentBuilder, MessageCreateOptions, EmbedBuilder } from 'discord.js';
```

Already tried to remove node_modules and install it again

- node v18.12.1
- "jest": "^27.4.5"
- "discord.js": "^14.7.1",

Answer (score -2):

Downgrading your Node.js version to v16 may help fixing this issue. It helped for me.